# Mock state in react snapshot test?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, snapshot, react-testing-library

Hil,

I would like to complete the following snapshot test but I don't know how to pass in state which is required for the page to render.

```
test('test renders as per snapshot', () => {
        const state = {
            orderNumber: 1000000001,
            userID: 1234567,
          }
        const tree = renderer
            .create(<Order location={ state }></Order>)
            .toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
```

I get this error

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'orderNumber' of undefined
> 40 |       this.props.location.state.orderNumber;
```

Can someone please tell me how I can pass this to my snapshot test so it doesnt fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in the component as `<Order location={{ state }}></Order>` (notice the additional curly braces), as it's equal to `<Order location={{ state: state }}></Order>`

In your post, <Order location={ state }> means to pass in `state` as a variable as 'props', and `this.props.location.state` would be undefined, thus led to your error.

Comment: Ah so simple yet I spent ages looking for this, thank you very much this solves my issue.

Comment: I want to set state of a value to null . Below is the method I had tried but the state value is not getting updated. Could you please help?

`test.only("render component", () => {
    const state = {
      storeTabSelected: null
    };
    const component = (
        <HomePage state={state} />
    );
    render(component);
  });`

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing state in state object, and I think it makes more sense renaming to 'location':

```
test('test renders as per snapshot', () => {
        const location = {
            state: {
              orderNumber: 1000000001,
              userID: 1234567,
            }
          }
        const tree = renderer
            .create(<Order location={ location }></Order>)
            .toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
```